# Error creating webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to create a new Web Service client through STS IDE using the wsdl URL. I get error **"WSDL file has validation errors. Code generation may fail."** during wsdl validation phase.

```
Message: A problem occured while running WS-I WSDL conformance check:
org.eclipse.wst.wsi.internal.analyzser.WSIAnalyzerException: 
The WS-I Test Assertion Document (TAD) document was either 
not found or could not be processed. 
The WSDLAnalyzer was unable to validate the given WSDL file.
```

Is there a problem in the service itself or am i making any mistake in creating the client ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: first try it in SoapUI tool. to create ws-client.